# How to create doctrine model entities from db without symfony?

Tags: php, database, model, doctrine, migration

I want to add doctrine framework to my custom php project. How can I create model entities by db tables with doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What doctrine version are you using? With the latest version you can use this after install doctrine in your project:

> php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity

You must change the directory and the type (annotation, xml, yml), and you must have configured the connection to the database where the tables are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show me how to configure Doctrine. I'm not use any frameworks like Symfony and i havn't bin/console.bat file for this command

Comment: If you dont use any framework, you have to implement diferent things by your yourself. There are guides on internet about this; see "Getting started with doctrine" too.